# Archivos compilados en IIS

Tags: iis

Tengo la siguiente situación.
Me estoy haciendo cargo de un sistema que no se utilizo desde ya buen tiempo, el cual se necesita actualizar agregando unos módulos, el detalle es que nadie sabe cual es el proyecto que esta publicado, saben si es posible que los archivos que están compilados puedan regresar a la forma original ? es decir que se muestre los archivos del lado del cliente y del servidor

Ejemplo: personal.aspx y personal.aspx.cs

Comment: `saben si es posible que los archivos que están compilados puedan regresar a la forma original ` Respuesta rápida: No. Lo que quizás pueda ser es decompilar el sistema y analizar detenidamente.

Comment: personal.aspx y personal.aspx.cs no son archivos compilados, por lo tanto no hay que hacer nada, solo abrirlos con un editor de texto. Otra cosa es que esos archivos hagan referencia a dll's compiladas, aquí si que tenéis un problema

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Para decompilar una dll podes usar [ilspy](https://sourceforge.net/projects/ilspyportable/) o también la aplicación de [jetbrains](https://www.jetbrains.com/decompiler/) lo unico que no veras el código 100% legible pero te dara una idea bastante buena de que se trata, en mi caso uso ilspy. Espero que te sirva, saludos